# How to do two actions in conditional UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, update

In a query  as

```
SET @x = 1

UPDATE table1 SET
col2 = IF(col1 = 'y', @x:=0, @x:=@x+1)
```

Every time reaching the value of `y` in `col1`, I want to SET the `@x:=@x+1` and after that reset the `x` to 0.

In other words, I want to count the rows before the occurrence of rows ending to `col1 = 'y'`.

**EXAMPLE**

I want to `UPDATE` `col2` as follows. In the above-mentioned query, rows for `col2` is simply `0` for all `col1 = 'y'`.

```
id       col1       col2
1       d          1
2       s          2
3       w          3
4       y          4
5       s          1
6       c          2
7       y          3
8       s          1
9       y          2
10       s          1
```

Comment: This is not clear. Please clarify with a real example (table with values and expected result after the update.)

Comment: @ypercube I added an example.

Comment: There is no inherent order in the rows within a table. Your example is not ordered alphabetically. What do you want the result to be sorted by?

Comment: @SebastianMeine sorry I forgot to include the `PRIMARY_KEY`, which is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: removed mine answer with "IF(col1 = 'y', (@x:=@x+1), @x=0)" because it indeed didnt make any sense after the topicstarters update "In other words, I want to count the rows before the occurrence of rows ending to col1 = 'y'." off the topic starter...

Answer (score 2):

If mysql had window functions, it would be quite easy. However, it doesn't, and even though there are quite a few solutions that use variables, most of them (at least the ones I read) warn about potential problems due to the changing order of evaluation when it comes to emulation `PARTITION BY` part.

My solution doesn't use variables at all (I know, performance is gonna be terrible for big amount of data, but it seems to have no side effects). I hope it can be somehow useful :

I split the task into 2 parts , 1st - creating select statement that returns required rank/rownumber, and 2nd - update which is trivial (simple `update ... join`) .

(Example in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c3926/1, but I post it here as well )
Table :

```
 create table table1(table1_id int auto_increment not null primary key, 
  col1 char(1) not null,col2 int );    
insert into table1(col1)
values ('d'), ('a'), ('b'), ('y'), ('x')
, ('a'), ('g'), ('y'), ('d'), ('d'), ('d')
, ('t'),('b'), ('y'),('y');
```

SELECT which returns desired value (hopefully) in "rank_column":

```
select a.*, 
  (
  select count(1) from table1 c 
WHERE c.table1_id >      
    IFNULL
    (
      (
       select MAX(table1_id) as next_id 
       from table1 b where col1='Y' and b.table1_id <a.table1_id
      )
    ,0)

   and c.table1_id <= a.table1_id
  )
as rank_column
 from table1 a
```

Now update itself which just repeats previous select :

```
  UPDATE table1 curr_val 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
  select a.table1_id,  
  (
  select count(1) from table1 c 
WHERE c.table1_id >      
    IFNULL
    (
      (
       select MAX(table1_id) as next_id 
       from table1 b where col1='Y' and b.table1_id <a.table1_id
      )
    ,0)

   and c.table1_id <= a.table1_id
  )as rank_column

 from table1 a
)new_val ON (curr_val.table1_id = new_val.table1_id)
SET curr_val.col2 = new_val.rank_column
```